# Editando layout Table

Tags: html, css, css3, variáveis

Boa tarde!

Possuo conhecimento basico de CSS, e estou tendo muita dificuldade em concluir uma tarefa. Preciso criar um email para carrinho abandonado no Magento. Segue modelo que está.

```
<tr>
    <td>{{var row_item_row_number}}</td>
    <td><a href="{{store url="catalog/product/view" id="$row_item.product.id"}}">{{var row_item.name}}</a></td>
    <td align="center"><img src="{{thumbnail size="75" source="row_item.product"}}" alt="" /></td>
    <td>{{var row_item.product.description}}&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right">{{var row_item.price_incl_tax|formatPrice}}</td>
    <td align="right">{{var row_item.qty_ordered|formatDecimal}}</td>
    <td align="bottom">{{var row_item.row_total_incl_tax|formatPrice}}</td>
    <td align="right"><a href="{{store url="review/product/list" id="$row_item.product.id"}}">Leave a review</a></td>
</tr>
```

Eu precisava deixar ele basicamente parecido como o da foto, imagem  250 x 250 nome do produto ao lado direito com preço a baixo e botão comprar. Alguem saberia me dizer como estilizar, estou muito perdido pois como disse não possuo conhecimento algum de variavel. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

Fala cara blz?

Meio complicado te ajudar porque não dá pra visualizar seu código e também ficaria sem graça pra você se eu fizesse o html todo né? rs

Se o problema for somente fazer o layout e você souber como chamar as informações do Magento (como nome do produto, foto do produto etc) acredito que esse [artigo aqui](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/pt/articles/build-an-html-email-template-from-scratch--webdesign-12770) vai te ajudar muito

Só fazendo esse exemplo você já vai pegar bem o conceito.